# Material color splash lib

Tags: android, animation, background-color, material-design

Maybe a week ago I found lib which fills the view with color and animation.

Now I can't find it, maybe someone sought it?

Here is example of what I mean. Need the same as in calculator on delete, or dialer on start calling.
[image]

Comment: Guess you'll have to put that animation yourself on click of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was Reveal Effect from Android 21.

To do like this I just need to use this code

```
// previously invisible view
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

// create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
Animator anim =
    ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

// make the view visible and start the animation
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
anim.start();
```

Take from here [Use the Reveal Effect](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal)